# Receiving a NoClassDefFoundError even though jar is successfully downloaded via Maven and referenced in pom.xml

Tags: xml, eclipse, spring, maven, dependency-injection

Runtime exception I am receiving is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource
```

Even though there are no errors within my project and I've updated via 'Maven update' and running 'Maven clean install' builds successfully. The dependency in my pom.xml is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Have also tried with scope set to 'provided' and with no scope at all. 
Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: delete the dependency from your maven repository and try again.

Comment: Show the complete stactrace please. Where do you run your program in Eclipse or a webserver?

Comment: deleted dependency and added again, no difference. Found a similar problem on Stackoverflow and they solved the issue by adding the jar causing the problem to the /WEB-INF-lib folder so did that and upon running application again now getting 'Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException' runtime exception?

Comment: this would suggest there is no spring-beans dependency but again this is in the pom.xml so not sure why Maven is not picking up these jars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have found a workaround solution but still not sure how/why Eclipse is no longer picking up Maven dependencies from the pom. 
Instead I have had to go into the Maven dependencies folder and copy and paste all dependencies required into the /WEB-INF/lib folder and finally application has launched successfully again with no runtime exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

This error is different then ClassNotFoundException, the error means the class is in classpath but not suitable. So the problem isn't related to maven it should be jdk version or any other inconsistency.
Can you check your jdk version?

Comment: Hmm, my jdk version is 1.7

Comment: are you trying to run your application via eclipse or you deploy to app server? If you run via eclipse i suggest to check deployment assembly of your Project properties.

Comment: Deploying project from Eclipse onto local Tomcat 7

Comment: do you have maven inside your Project Settings -> Deployment Assembly list.
Maven Dependencies -> WEB-INF/lib

Comment: yes Maven Dependencies is there ready to be deployed in project properties